# second ajax call inside repeating forms does not work

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a repeating forms and each form has button to reset and ajax call associated with it. The first ajax works fine but then the ajax on the rests of the form giving me error messages. The second ajax tries to call viewaction and gives me null pointer.

Am I doing any thing wrong and strange.

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="${employeeBean.id}"/>
            <f:viewAction action="${employeeBean.loadOrder()}"/>
        </f:metadata>
     <div jsf:id="employee-list">
         <ui:repeat var="employee" value="#{employeeList}">
                        <tr data-bdd-id="employee-element">                   
                            <td data-bdd-id="employee-type">label</td>
                            <td data-bdd-id="employee-status">status</td>
                            <td>
                               <form jsf:id="employee-form" jsf:prependId="false">                                                              
                                            <button class="btn btn-delete" 
                                                    jsf:action="#{employeeBean.resetOrDeleteemployee(employee)}"
                                                    jsf:onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')">
                                                Reset
                                                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="employee-form  employee-list generate-login" />
                                           </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Stop using `prependId="false"` and retry.

Comment: @BalusC. I tried but same issue

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? (and please always mention this in every single JSF question, see also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: @BalusC. I am using Jsf version 2

Comment: This is insufficient information. "JSF 2" is more a specification version. Which JSF implementation exactly are you using? E.g. "Mojarra" or "MyFaces". And then its exact version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.2.11" or "MyFaces 2.2.8". You can find this detail in JARs or in server log during webapp's startup.

Comment: @BalusC.We are using Mojarra 2.2.8

Comment: which browser are you using?